# Update certificate for an individual enrollment in azure DPS via REST API

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-dps

I am doing operations on azure DPS via REST apis. I am able to post a new provision successfully in "Create new individual enrollment", via REST API.The Url is used is, "https://name.azure-devices-provisioning.net/enrollments/registrationId?api-version=2019-03-31";. My current task is to update the certificate for an individual enrollment in DPS. I am extracting the body of the certificate and attaching it to the request body and doing the PUT operation. But I am getting an error saying "Enrollment already exists with different cert info". I am providing the content-type and authorization sas token as headers. And in request body, I am passing the eTag along. I guess I have cleared all the pre-requisites for an update operation. Please help me to understand if I am doing something wrong here. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can start by step by step process where I have successfully updated my x509 certificate with [Azure DPS via REST API call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iot-dps/createorupdateindividualenrollment/createorupdateindividualenrollment#request-headers). I hope this helps with your query.

**Step1:** Create the Individual Enrollment with the x509 certificate, pass it in base64 format. Please make a note of the 'eTag' value in the response.

[image: 61573-image.png]

Verify In the Azure DPS portal. I see the thumbprint matches my x509 certificate.

[image: 61603-image.png]

**Step 2:** Now time for updating the existing Enrollment with a new certificate. use the base64 format. use the "If-Match" in the request header and the value is the "eTag" obtained/copied from the previous step.

**Below image shows the Request Header with the "If-match =eTag" for updating the existing entity.**
[image: 61544-image.png]

**Finally, we can see the response is a success for the update operation.**

[image: 61518-image.png]

**Verify In the Azure DPS portal.** I see the thumbprint matches my new x509 certificate.

[image: 61588-image.png]

**Sample Request body, in case, if it is useful to anyone.**

```
 {
  "attestation": {
         "type": "x509",
         "X509": {
            "clientCertificates": {
                                "primary":{
                                 "certificate":"base64 string of your cert"
                                 }
                                 }    
                                   }
     },
 "registrationId":"testenrollment10",
 "capabilities":{"iotEdge":false},
 "provisioningStatus": "enabled"
 }
```

Please leave your comment below to this response if you need further help in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

For updating the individual enrollment in DPS you also have to add the etag value in the request header. The header property name for this is `If-Match`. For details see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iot-dps/createorupdateindividualenrollment/createorupdateindividualenrollment#request-headers

Comment: I did try adding etag as the value in If-Match and even i tried to keep it as *. Still I was getting the same error. Certificate updation is not happening via this method

Comment: Can you please share the activity id for this request.